# Difference between two observables

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, rxjs, angular6

Let's say I have two observables.

The first observable is an array of certain listings:

```
[
    {id: 'zzz', other props here...},
    {id: 'aaa', ...},
    {id: '007', ...}
    ... and more over time
]
```

The second observable is an array of ignored listings:

```
[
    {id: '007'}, // only id, no other props
    {id: 'zzz'}
    ... and more over time
]
```

The result should be a new observable of listings (first observable) but must not have any of the ignored listings:

```
[
    {id: 'aaa', other props here...}
    ... and more over time
]
```

This is what I have now before posting:

```
obs2.pipe(withLatestFrom(obs1, ? => ?, filter(?));
```

Comment: What if the listing is emitted on the first observable before it is emitted as an ignored one on the second one? Can you guarantee that that won't happen?

Comment: Also, since you clearly need to buffer the second observable, do you want that buffer to live (and grow) forever or is there some condition to remove them again (ie, any listing can only occur in the first observable once, time-based,..)?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test it out, but I think it should be ok:

```
combineLatest(values$, excluded$).pipe(
  map(([values, excluded]) => {
    // put all the excluded IDs into a map for better perfs
    const excludedIds: Map<string, undefined> = excluded.reduce(
      (acc: Map<string, undefined>, item) => {
        acc.set(item.id, undefined)
        return acc;
      },
      new Map()
    );

    // filter the array, by looking up if the current
    // item.id is in the excluded list or not
    return values.filter(item => !excludedIds.has(item.id))
  })
)
```

**Explanation:**

Using `combineLatest` you'll always be warned no matter where you get the update from. If you use `withLatestFrom` as in your example, it'll trigger an update only if the `values$` observable is updated. But if the `excluded$` changes, it wouldn't trigger an update in your case.

Then get all the excluded IDs into a map instead of an array as we'll need to know whether a given ID should be excluded or not. Looking into a map is wayyyyy faster than looking into an array.

Then just filter the values array.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, what you'll want to do is

1. Aggregate the incoming items over time
2. Aggregate the ids that are to be ignored over time
3. Finally, as both of the above streams emit over time, emit a resulting list of items that don't include the ignored ids.

Given the above, below is a rough example you could try. As noted towards the bottom, you'll get different results depending on the cadence of the first two streams because, well, thats's what happens with async. To show that, I'm simulating a random delay in the emission of things over time.

Hope this helps!

P.S.: The below is Typescript, assuming rxjs@^6.

```
import { BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, of, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { delay, map, scan, concatMap } from "rxjs/operators";

/**
 * Data sources
 */

// Just for showcase purposes... Simulates items emitted over time
const simulatedEmitOverTime = <T>() => (source: Observable<T>) =>
  source.pipe(
    concatMap(thing => of(thing).pipe(delay(Math.random() * 1000)))
  );

interface Thing {
  id: string;
}

// Stream of things over time
const thingsOverTime$ = of(
  { id: "zzz" },
  { id: "aaa" },
  { id: "007" }
).pipe(
  simulatedEmitOverTime()
);

// Stream of ignored things over time
const ignoredThingsOverTime$ = of(
  { id: "007" },
  { id: "zzz" }
).pipe(
  simulatedEmitOverTime()
);


/**
 * Somewhere in your app
 */

// Aggregate incoming things
// `scan` takes a reducer-type function
const aggregatedThings$ = thingsOverTime$.pipe(
  scan(
    (aggregatedThings: Thing[], incomingThing: Thing) =>
      aggregatedThings.concat(incomingThing),
    []
  )
);

// Create a Set from incoming ignored thing ids
// A Set will allow for easy filtering over time
const ignoredIds$ = ignoredThingsOverTime$.pipe(
  scan(
    (excludedIdSet, incomingThing: Thing) =>
      excludedIdSet.add(incomingThing.id),
    new Set<string>()
  )
);

// Combine stream and then filter out ignored ids
const sanitizedThings$ = combineLatest(aggregatedThings$, ignoredIds$)
  .pipe(
    map(([things, ignored]) => things.filter(({ id }) => !ignored.has(id)))
  );

// Subscribe where needed
// Note: End result will vary depending on the timing of items coming in
// over time (which is being simulated here-ish)
sanitizedThings$.subscribe(console.log);
```