# Getting the difference between two Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to get the difference between two very similar observables, removing the values of one from the other based on a shared ID field. I've tried the answer from this question:

[Difference between two observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50547424/difference-between-two-observables)

```ts
const inActiveUsers = combineLatest(storedUsers$, activeUsers$).pipe(
  map(([storedUsers, activeUsers]) => {
    const activeUsersIds: Map<string, undefined> = activeUsers.reduce(
      (acc: Map<string, undefined>, item) => {
        acc.set(item.id, undefined)
        return acc;
      },
      new Map()
    );
    return storedUsers.filter(item => !activeUsersIds.has(item.id));
  })
)

inActiveUsers.subscribe(inActiveUsers => {
  this.inActiveUsers = inActiveUsers;
});
```

but it just seems to take out one of the records (the last one presumably?).

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: I dont understand. What type of storedUsers$ and activeUsers$? Observable? What are you using?

Comment: I don't think the concept is good. I would do it completely differently. I just don't know what types of variables.

Answer (score 1):

My soution, but I just don't know if that's what you need.

```js
const storedUsers$: Observable<{ id: string }[]> = this.store.select(storedUsersSelector);
const activeUsers$: Observable<{ id: string }[]> = this.store.select(activeUsersSelector);

// API: export function combineLatest<O1 extends ObservableInput<any>, O2 extends ObservableInput<any>>(sources: [O1, O2]): Observable<[ObservedValueOf<O1>, ObservedValueOf<O2>]>;

const inActiveUsers = combineLatest([storedUsers$, activeUsers$]).pipe(
    map(([storedUsers, activeUsers]) => {
        // save just IDs
        const ids: string[] = activeUsers.map(item => item.id);

        // if contain then add result
        return storedUsers.filter(item => ids.includes(item.id));
    })
);
```

Comment: Hi there. Thanks so much. This seems very close and I can see you mention that you think the idea is flawed or should be done a different way. What I am actually trying to do is find the inactive users, so I am looking for "if doesn't contain then add result". I'm happy to consider a completely different way. I'm just looking to get the records from one observable that do NOT appear in the second observable.

Comment: Actually, it's simple to correct this, i think? I'm just going with:       

`return storedUsers.filter(item => ids.includes(item.id));`

Comment: includes will get true of contain. It is true: `[0, 1, 2].includes(1)` and it is false: `[0, 1, 2].includes(3)`

Comment: `filter` get filtered array by inner function. If true item will contain in result, if not item wont contain them. So `return storedUsers.filter(...)` work. Ofc, "id" must be in this `item`.